# Enter key does not work in search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Tried to search for this guys sorry. Input in the search box doesnt work (or search) when you hit enter only when the user clicks the search button. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var url = "http://asla.org/awardssearch.html";
        url += "?s=" + $('#GoogleCSE').val();
        window.location = url;
    });
    $('#GoogleCSE').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == '13') {
            $("#submit").click();
            }
        else {
            //do nothing :)
        }
    });

});
</script>

<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
      <div class="search">
        <input id="GoogleCSE" type="text" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" value="Search All Awards" name="Search All Awards" />
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Search" />
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Entering a search term and hitting enter does not work for me in that fiddle.

Comment: Really strange behaviour. If you add a breakpoint on the `window.location = url;` line, everything works.

Answer (score 3):

If you changed your `#submit` element's `type` to "submit", you wouldn't need to manually handle this yourself anyway as this is default browser behaviour:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
```

Now rather than handling the `#submit` button's click event, we can instead handle the `form` element's `submit` event:

```
$('form[role="search"]').submit(function() {

    var url = "http://asla.org/awardssearch.html";
    url += "?s=" + $('#GoogleCSE').val();
    window.location = url;

});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/xLpkvbu0/).

Comment: Thanks very much but the results(data from input) doesnt seem to be passing doesnt display through the search url(/awardssearch.html), could this be a variable issue?

if it helps the I have it on dev

http://staging.asla.org/2014awards/index.html

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Through `$("#submit").click()` you're just triggering the click handlers added by yourself, not the controls default behavior when you click on it.

Use `yourForm.submit()` instead and change the url in its callback:

```
$("#yourForm").submit(function() {
    var url = "http://asla.org/awardssearch.html";
    url += "?s=" + $('#GoogleCSE').val();
    window.location = url;
});
```

Comment: Thanks could you make into a fiddle for me so I can see what you mean?

Comment: The variable doesnt seem to be passing, its doing what I want it to do just not opening the external search site in the window location any advice ?